# Cisco's Command Lookup Tool Parser with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, cisco

I want to create a python script that connects to Cisco's Command Lookup Tool site authenticates with my credentials, populates necessary fields and searches for all commands that I need and provides the explanation. Cisco's site look's like this:

[image]

I was able to get to this point by using below script:

```
import requests

USERNAME = 'username' 
PASSWORD = 'password'

DATAURL = 'https://tools.cisco.com/Support/CLILookup/cltSearchAction.do'

session = requests.session()

req_headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

formdata = {
    'userid': USERNAME,
    'password': PASSWORD,
    'login-button' : 'Login'
}

# Authenticate
r = session.post(DATAURL, data=formdata, headers=req_headers, allow_redirects=True)
print r.headers
print r.status_code
```

After this, script needs to populate drop-down menus accordingly and present the results. I used chrome's inspection tool to get necessary information. I found out when user populates drop-down fields and presses submit button chrome sends below GET request to the server:

```
https://tools.cisco.com/Support/CLILookup/cltSearchAction.do?AT=getCommandList&IndexId=1&IndexOptionId=1473&SearchPhrase=&PageNumber=0
```

Unfortunately, this link doesn't work on it's own, so I need help on how to approach this problem and get desirable results.

Thank you very much.